# Can't install xmlwriter, gd and bcmath for PHP7.0 on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, apt, php7

I digging on stack exchainge whole morning and can't find right solution. I find a bunch of non existing repository and can't install `xmlwriter`, `gd` and `bcmath` for PHP 7.0.

I have linux server based on Apache2, PHP7.0, MySql, phpMyAdmin and want to add ZABBIX on server and he require this 3 PHP extensions.

I change `php.ini`and enble this plugins but I not have it installed.

I try this like example:

```
> apt-get install php7.0-gd
> apt-get install php-gd
> apt-get install php7-gd
```

but nothing work. Also I not find anything in repository.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because PHP7 is not in Jessie proper. Jessie was declared stable before 7.0 was deemed ready to be included (Debian maintainers tend to have high standards for that) so it was left out.

That said, you can install it via the [`backports`](https://backports.debian.org/) archive. What you'll need to do is create a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/10-backports.list` with the following entry:

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Then run `apt-get update` to integrate the package list.

Once you've done that, you can type `apt-cache search php7` and you should see a list of all PHP7 packages that are now available via apt-get.

I just checked, and `php7.0-gd` is currently among them.

**EDIT**: My bad, backports doesn't have PHP7, [DotDeb](https://www.dotdeb.org/) does. This is the source you'll need:

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
```

Comment: Are you sure you have not stretch or sid in your sources @Shadur?

Comment: Hi, good point but have issue: `W: GPG error: http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E9C74FEEA2098A6E
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
`

Comment: I'm not shure about stretch or sid

Comment: Look at the instructions on the dotdeb site. You need to import their GPG key so you can verify the signatures.